# Módulo prestashop tpv

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, tpv

Hola me han comentado realizar este proyecto:
Buenas Samuel, te comento.

Actualmente trabajamos con un TPV comprado aqui: https://www.pos-tpv.com/es/ pero como te he comentado viene con el código capado. El prestashop de Bodas Outlet es el 1.6.0.14 y para poder coger las mejoras de este tpv tendriamos que actualizar la version. Se han metido numerosas cosas customizadas en este prestashop, la gran mayoria de las veces mediante overrides, pero algunas no, y ahora mismo no es el momento de actualizar.

La interfaz podrás verla en esa url. Tendriamos que hacer una interfaz similar (los colores y tal ya los hablaremos mas adelante, no me preocupa y con que no sea horriblemente fea la interfaz me va a valer).

La interacción es la siguiente:

Pantalla inicial con tres opciones
Pedido para encargar y recoger posteriormente
El cliente mira las muestras de la tienda y elige las que le gusta, y hace un encargo ya de cantidades de cada muestra (del espejo tal 20 unidades, del boli tal 140 unidades...), la tienda lo informatiza y crea un pedido que almacén recibirá y le mandará a la semana siguiente a la tienda para que la tienda avise al cliente y venga a recoger su encargo.
Que la siguiente pantalla sea un formulario que pida el nombre, apellidos del cliente y dos telefonos (uno obligatorio movil, y otro opcional).
Que la siguiente pantalla ya sea la del tpv y el tpv ya haya registrado a ese cliente con nombre apellidos y telefonos y cree un carrito con lo que se vaya metiendo en el tpv y luego ese carrito se confirme en pedido cuando se acabe la compra.
El estado en el que tiene que quedar el pedido confirmado te lo digo luego, depende como se haya pagado.
Grabar en la tabla de la caja de la tienda el registro correspondiente del importe del pedido, id pedido, fecha, empleado que lo graba...
Actualizar nota interna del pedido con datos de la operacion.
Pedido para enviar a domicilio
El cliente mira las muestras de la tienda, elige las que le gusta, y hace el pedido pero no para recogerlo en la misma tienda la semana siguiente, sino que se le manda a casa directamente desde la central.
Siguiente pantalla sea un formulario que pida el nombre del cliente, direccion, telefonos... lo mismo que pide prestashop para registrarse. 
Que la siguiente pantalla ya sea la del tpv y el tpv ya haya registrado a ese cliente con nombre apellidos y telefonos y cree un carrito con lo que se vaya metiendo en el tpv y luego ese carrito se confirme en pedido cuando se acabe la compra.
Grabar en la tabla de la caja de la tienda el registro correspondiente del importe del pedido, id pedido, fecha, empleado que lo graba...
El estado en el que tiene que quedar el pedido confirmado te lo digo luego, depende como se haya pagado.
Actualizar nota interna del pedido con datos de la operacion.
Pedido de venta directa de muestras
La tienda tiene cosas en stock que puede vender directamente. Si elige esta opcion, hay una tabla que relaciona el id_employee logado (tienda logada) con el id_customer "generico" para pedidos de este tipo. No vamos a pedir nombre apellidos y telefonos para alguien que viene a comprar un boli. Lo que hacemos es usar un cliente generico de cada tienda y listo, todos los pedidos de muestra se hacen a nombre de ese cliente generico.
Grabar en la tabla de la caja de la tienda el registro correspondiente del importe del pedido, id pedido, fecha, empleado que lo graba...
El estado en el que tiene que quedar el pedido confirmado te lo digo luego, depende como se haya pagado.
Actualizar nota interna del pedido con datos de la operacion.
Pedido de muestras
La tienda vende muestras segun el punto anterior, y luego nos hace pedidos de esas muestras a nosotros como central para que se la repongamos y no se queden con la exposición vacia. 
Que la siguiente pantalla ya sea la del tpv. Según el id_employee logado que coja el id del customer generico de esa tienda y que haga el pedido a nombre de ese cliente.
No hay que grabar nada en caja.
Hay que dejar ese pedido en un estado "Pendiente preparacion envio de muestras" que ya te diré que id es y ya esta.
Actualizar nota interna del pedido con datos de la operacion.
La pantalla del TPV tendrá un buscador que buscará por referencia, id_product, ean13, UPC o nombre del producto. Aparecerán unas fotitos de los produtos que vayan cumpliendo el criterio de busqueda a partir de que escriba por ejemplo 3 caracteres (similar al que te he enseñado antes). Se selecciona la foto y se añade al listado de productos del pedido abajo y se va guardando en el id_cart creado y tal. 
Los campos de la linea serian iguales a lo que te he mostrado en el tpv que tenemos ahora, y con la posiblidad de editar cualquiera de: nombre del producto, cantidad, descuento respecto del PVP (por % o por €) y precio unitario. Te daré acceso a nuestro backoffice para que lo veas bien. 
Cuando se haya terminado de meter articulos, se selecciona el metodo de pago:
Pagado 100% con tarjeta
Pagado 100% en efectivo 
Pago parcial de x€ a la confirmacion y el resto a la recogida (este metodo no esta disponible para envios a domicilio, los envios a domicilio siempre deben quedar pagados).
Si es un pedido de muestras no hay que seleccionar metodo de pago, eso ya nosotros se lo facturamos por otro lado. Esto es solo una interfaz para nosotros recibir esos pedidos de reposicion y nos dan igual los totales, que son irreales porque las franquicias tienen costos diferentes, y tambien nos da igual el metodo de pago.
Dependiendo del metodo de pago, habra que grabar en el ps_orders el campo "payment" que ya te dire que textos poner. 
Establecer metodo de envio en el pedido a crear (id_carrier y module name)
Si el pedido es para encargar y recoger, el metodo de envio (module_name) a grabar se tiene que llamar tpvtienda (usamos eso para otras cosas) y el id_carrier 48. Tambien hay que rellenar el payment, ya te dire detalles, todo esto es para que te hagas una idea lo mas general posible.
Si el pedido es para domicilio, hay que preguntar en el tpv antes de grabar si la tienda quiere usar Economy (id_carrier 63) o Urgente (id_carrier 82). Module name y payment ya te dire.
Si el pedido es de venta directa el carrier igual TPVTienda, modulename y payment ya te dire.
Si el pedido es de muestras ya te dire. 
Al grabar el pedido tendrá que convertir el carrito en pedido (prestashop ya tiene funciones hechas para esto como ya sabrás) y guardarlo en nuestro listado para que se prepare, se envie etc etc. 
Al grabar el pedido vendrá una pantalla de confirmacion donde generará el ticket con los datos del comercio que lo ha vendido (se cogerá de la tabla de Franquicias que tenemos), los datos del cliente, productos y pie de ticket. 
Es sabido el rollo que tiene prestashop con los decimales, habra que tner en cuenta que si al producto se le mete descuentos en la linea correspondiente (lo usamos mucho esto) todo tiene que cuadrar bien. El tpv actual no cuadra y es un caos.
Añadir finalmente una opcion general que se va a llamar MODO EVENTO. El modo evento es un boton que si lo activas, todo lo que añadas al tpv tendrá un % de descuento prefijado en cada producto que se añada. La pantallita de configuracion del modo evento tendrá 3 lineas agrupadas de dos en dos: 
Hasta ____ unidades aplicar **_ de descuento
Hasta ____ unidades aplicar _** de descuento
Para mas de ____ unidades aplicar ____ de descuento
Si se activa el modo evento, todo lo que se pique dandole a la foto, al agregarse, el precio ya debe ir recalculandose en base a esas 3 franjas y a la cantidad que se vaya introduciendo de cada producto.
Todo esto pensado para un pc generalmente, pero tambien cuando tenemos un evento y viene muchisima gente a comprar, quiero que esto se pueda abrir en el movil de cada vendedor y lo puedan usar, asi que debe ser responsive y muy rapido y clarito, tal y como lo estamos describiendo creo que es perfecto. En los eventos trabajamos con factureros de papel porque este tpv no funciona rapido y es una lata. Lo que pretendo al hacer uno nuevo es ademas que en los eventos se pueda trabajar con el movil de cada uno y no haya que estar luego 1 semana picando factureros.
Tambien quiero usar la camara del movil para escanear codigos de barra y que se agreguen directamente al pedido, como la del movil es una camara optica y el "reconocimiento de imagenes" no se como andará con php o que habrá, de momento no te lo voy a pedir para meterlo porque no quiero que nos coja el toro, pero tenlo en mente y si esto que yo creo que no es facil tu supieras por algo que hayas visto por ahi que es facil, tambien lo metemos. 
Lo que espero de la intefaz de pc es algo como lo que tenemos no muy complejo:

Lo que espero de interfazo movil en plan muy feo pero para que me entiendas como irian las pantallas:

Creo que con esto ya tienes una idea para darme precio y plazo. Tenemos un evento en abril, asi que deberia estar para el 15 de marzo como muy tarde para tener 15 dias de depuracion y poderlo usar sin miedo. Si esta antes, mejor. Es una parrafada pero no tiene nada de complejidad, todo gestión y horas.

Ya me comentas y cuando empecemos empiezas a plantear la interfaz y a medida que avances te doy detalles de qué tienes que poner en cada sitio y cada estado para que todo funcione como debe. Te daré acceso a un presatshop de pruebas, creo que lo suyo es que plantees esto como un modulo, y asi tenemos mucho ganado para luego actualizar etc etc. Si ves que hay algo en el mercado que lo podemos comprar y adaptar, sientete libre de decirmelo tambien y lo vemos y asi ahorramos tiempo.

Portate bien con los precios que si vamos bien te voy a encargar muchas cosas ;-) no suelo ser muy pejigueras ni te voy a marear una semana con "este boton mas pequeño y mas centrado" o "este color cambialo". Vamos a que las cosas se vean bien, sean faciles de usar y no sean horriblemente feas. con eso estoy contento jeje

Necesito haber si alguien a echo algo parecido para q empezar, tengo conocimientos de módulos php MySQl necesito alguien que me asesore.

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, no me lo puedo leer todo, por encima a ver si lo entendi: tienes que hacer un módulo prestashop en algo menos de un mes y ¿no has hecho modulos para este software antes? No te metas...
 Tienen un problema con su tienda si no pueden actualizar y una versión ya bastante vieja... Customizar un prestashop es infinitamente mas fácil que hacer módulos, pero luego vienen estas cosas... y no todo se puede hacer con módulos.

Comment: Hola era por si alguien había realizado módulos antes de este tipo tpv, para asesorarme sobre todo en precio y demás pero no te preocupes yo lo valoro. gracias